# C++ How do I print elements of an array but leave out repeats?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

My assignment is to have the user type in how many elements are in an array then enter integer number to be put in the array. I then have to  sort through the array and find the largest number and print out the elements of the array but if there is a repeat then only print that number one time. I also have to print out the number of times each element in the array occurs. For example if the user types in that there is 5 elements then enters 2, 1, 2, -3, 2 then it should print -3  with 1 count, 1 with 1 count, and 2 with 3 count. So far I have it so it will print out the elements and delete the repeats but I cant get it to print out the correct number of occurrences for each element. This is my code so far.

```
            void findRepeats(int numbers[], int num)
            {
                int instances = 0;

                cout << "Number" << " " << "Occurrences" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                {
                    bool matching = false;
                    instances = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; (j < i); j++)
                    {
                        if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                        {
                            instances++;
                            matching = true;

                        }

                    }
                    if (!matching) 
                        cout << numbers[i] << "      " << instances << endl;

                }
            }
```

Right now its saying all number occur only 1 time

Comment: If you are able to use the std algorithm library, take a look at std::sort and std::count.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that you could take, is to sort the numbers first, before deciding how many duplicates there are.  That way, it will be easier to avoid printing results for the same number more than once, and you also won't have to loop through the entire array for each number.

```
void findRepeats(int numbers[], int num);

int main(){

  int array[] = {2, 1, 2, -3, 2};
  findRepeats(array,5);

}

void findRepeats(int numbers[], int num) {

    //sort the array first
    std::sort(numbers, numbers + num);

    int last = numbers[0];
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Number of Occurrences\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (last == numbers[i]) {
            ++count;
        } else {
            cout << last << "      " << count << '\n';
            count = 1;
        }
        last = numbers[i];
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        cout << last << "      " << count << '\n';
    }

}
```

**prints:**

```
Number of Occurrences
-3      1
1      1
2      3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `map` or `unordered_map` to, well..., map the integer to the number of it's occurrences. It makes things quite simple, as it basically takes care of the duplicates for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

void reportCounts(const int numbers[], const size_t size){
    unordered_map<int, unsigned int> counts;

    //unfortunately range-for here would a little PIA to apply
    //or at least I don't know convenient way
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        counts [ numbers[i] ]++; //increase `count` of i-th number
    }

    //print results
    for(auto count : counts ){
        cout << count.first << ' ' << count.second << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int array[] = {2, 1, 2, -3, 2};
    reportCounts(array,5);
}
```

Since it's an assignment I am leaving figuring out the c++ shenaningans to you and http://cppreference.com. Keywords are `map`, `map::iterator` and maybe *associative container* which `map` in an example of.

I do understand that it might be harder to understand than plain implementation of some algorithm, but this is probably close to optimal solution in modern c++, and putting effort into understanding how and why it works should prove beneficial. One should notice how much less of code had to be written, and no algorithm had to be invented. Less implementation time, less place to make mistakes, less testing.

Answer (score 0):

Search your array. For every integer, either record it, or increment your count of it. Repeat process till done, then print it.

How? you say? One approach would be to use parallel arrays to store the unique integers found, and another to store the count of integers. Then print the unique integers and their counts.

Code example of simple search algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print(vector<int> valueArray,vector<int> countArray){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < valueArray.size(); ++i){
        cout<<"Found value "<<valueArray[i]<<": "<<countArray[i]<<" times."<<endl;
    }
}
void findRepeats(vector<int> testArray,vector<int> &valueArray,vector<int> &countArray){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < testArray.size(); ++i){
        if(valueArray.size() == 0){
            valueArray.push_back(testArray[i]);
            countArray.push_back(1);
        }else{
            bool newEntry = true;
            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < valueArray.size(); ++j){
                if(testArray[i] == valueArray [j]){
                    countArray[j]++;
                    newEntry = false;
                    break;//After find, break out of j-for-loop to save time.
                }
            }
            if(newEntry){
                valueArray.push_back(testArray[i]);
                countArray.push_back(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){

    vector<int> testArray;                  //To store all integers entered.
    vector<int> valueArray;                 //To store non-copied integers, dynamically, else handle it yourself.
    vector<int> countArray;                 //To count increments of numbers found, dynamically, else handle it yourself.

    testArray = {0,2,5,4,1,3,6,2,5,9,8,7,4,1,2,6,5,4,8,3,2,1,5,8,6,9,8,7,4,4,5,6,8,2,1,3,0,0,1,2,0,2,5,8};//Dummy data.
    findRepeats(testArray,valueArray,countArray);//Function to find statistics on testArray.

    cout<<"\nPrinting found characters, and number of times found: "<<endl;
    print(valueArray,countArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Output would be something like:

```
Printing found characters, and number of times found:
Found value 0: 4 times.
Found value 2: 7 times.
Found value 5: 6 times.
Found value 4: 5 times.
Found value 1: 5 times.
Found value 3: 3 times.
Found value 6: 4 times.
Found value 9: 2 times.
Found value 8: 6 times.
Found value 7: 2 times.
```

In the above, I used vectors for simplicity, but if you must do so with c-style arrays, one approach would be to create all three vectors the same size, and keep one integer counter for number of indices used in the valueArray and countArray; they should share, since they're related 1 to 1. And you will need to pass it to the findRepeats function as well.

Having arrays of the same size will ensure that your values and counts will fit in your array; this would happen if every number entered was unique.